# One variable for two function in JS

Tags: javascript, forms, function, input

I dev a little game, and I went at the beginning of the game, the gravity at -40, but after if the player wants to change it, he can.

I have this form:

```
<form>
     <input type="text" id="userInput" />
     <input type="submit" onclick="otherG();" />
</form>
```

My gravity is:

```
function initScene() {
   blablabla
   scene.setGravity(new THREE.Vector3(0, -40, 0));
   blablabla
}
```

How can I change the -40 by the input of the user, and allow the scene (no need do f5) ?

The form appear when the user wants to change gravity via a keypress.

PS: I'm using three.js and physijs.

Comment: Submit is refreshing the page. Add `return false` at the end of the function to prevent this.

Comment: the question appears to be about how to use user input in your code. make a variable and set it to the value that the user enters. use this variable in your code.

Comment: But not `scene.setGravity(new THREE.Vector3(0, someNewValue, 0));` ?

Comment: Yes, but in intscene() i have many thing like draw car, the ground...

Comment: isn't `scene` a global var?

Comment: scene is global var use in many thing on my intiscene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this

HTML :

```
<form onsubmit="return otherG();">
   <input type="text" id="userInput" />
   <input type="submit" value="Change Gravity" />
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
var gravity = -40; // default value
var doc = document;

function otherG() {
    gravity = doc.getElementById("userInput").value;
    updateScene();
    return false;
}

function updateScene() {
  blablabla
  scene.setGravity(new THREE.Vector3(0, gravity, 0));
  blablabla
}
```

Comment: in need change onclick="otherG"();" ?

Comment: ok, updateScene and initScene is same function or not ?
because initScen draw all, but updatescene do same with new gravity ?

Comment: when i set the new gravity, the game freeze, i initscen with -40, if want chnage, the form call setnewgravity, and put 5, but frezze after that